# VisualBrush fade animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make VisualBrush that automatically fades in/out when set, but unfortunately it doesn't work as it should. Instead of actually fading it disappears or appears right away totally ignoring storyboard - or I'm trying to catch wrong event.

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="CustomHatchBrush" TileMode="None" Viewport="0,0,100,100" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewbox="0,0,100,100" ViewboxUnits="Absolute">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Canvas>
            <Canvas.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Opacity)" RepeatBehavior="1x" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Unloaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Opacity)" RepeatBehavior="1x" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Canvas.Triggers>
            <Rectangle Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Orange" />
            <Rectangle Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="{DynamicResource CaretBrush}" />
        </Canvas>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

I generally want to use it inside Template of ListBoxItem as BorderBrush, something like that:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Border x:Name="ca" BorderThickness="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Padding="0">
        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="4" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Padding="0">
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Border>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Prop1}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Prop2}" Value="true"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="ca" Value="{DynamicResource CustomHatchBrush}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Prop1}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Prop2}" Value="false"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="ca" Value="{DynamicResource CustomHatchBrush2}"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Prop1}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="ca" Value="Transparent"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I tried many ways of applying storyboard, for example inside bindings, but it always finishes instantly completely ignoring Storyboard duration.

What am I missing? This control works fine in general (objects have name and have multiple instances, so something could go wrong), I just can't create visual effect that I would want to achieve.

Comment: Could you please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Did you try to increase the `Duration`?

Comment: Note that at least the Unloaded animation can't work, because it is triggered *after* the element was unloaded.

Comment: @mm8 Yes, I tried even second and it didn't do anything.

Comment: @Clemens I have exactly identical transition inside ControlTemplate being content of a Button, and it works at least partially. Maybe I didn't see fading out being absent (it's only 0.2s, so I could miss that), but I will check that tomorrow.

Comment: @Khaine: So where is your MCVE?